# Add class TextEditorField EasyAdmin 4

Tags: symfony, easyadmin, trix

is there a way to add a custom class to a specific tag with the TextEditorField - EasyAdmin : https://symfony.com/bundles/EasyAdminBundle/current/fields/TextEditorField.html

This field is using trix editor : https://trix-editor.org

I'd like to do something like this :

```
public function configureFields(string $pageName): iterable {
    return [
        TextEditorField::new('description', 'Description')->setNumOfRows(30)->setTrixEditorConfig([
            'blockAttributes' => [
                'default' => ['tagName' => 'p'],
                'heading1' => ['tagName' => 'h2', 'class' => 'myClass'],
            ]
        ])
    ];
}
```

Actually, I want to add the class 'myClass' to all the h2 tags.